# Detect Whether the email recipient mail address is encoded or not - EWS API

Tags: api, exchangewebservices

I am retrieving email message using the EWS API from office 365. When I try to retrieve,the send mail recipient email address , the non-ASCII email address or Unicode email address are retrieved in some encoded format(api returning in encoded format). Is there any attribute or something like that to detect whether the email is actually in encoded format or not, so that I can decode that.

```
EmailMessage emailMessage;

foreach (var recipient in emailMessage.ToRecipients)
{
    ERecipient recip = new ERecipient();                                    
    recip.EmailAddress = recipient.Address;
}
```

How can I identify whether recipient Address is actually encoded?

Comment: Can you show a sample of one of the addresses (at least the start of the address)

Comment: example email Address : =?UTF-8?B?2KfZhNiu2LfZiNin2Kog2KfZhNiq2Yog2KrYrNmF2Lkg2KjZitmGINit2YHYuCDYp9mE2YLYsdin2ZPZhiDYp9mE2YPYsdmK2YUg2YjZgdmH2YXZhyDZhdmF2Kcg2KfZlNmF?=@test.com .

Answer (score 5):

The mail address is BASE64 encoding, the "B?" in the address stands for Base64 encoding.
Similarly,  if the email address form is `"=? GH2312? Q? = ae = a3 = a3? ="`, it represent the formal character set is encoded as quoted-printable.

Q - Quote Printable

B - BASE64

U - UUENCODE

So from my experience, you can call the decoding function, if it's not start with "=?" and end with "? =", the mail is not encoding,  we don’t need decoding.

Comment: Ya that's right ...If i decode the mail i can get correct mail id . Before i decode that i need to check whether the email is encoded or not , i can use regex for that but My question is whether API is providing any attribute which tells whether the email is encoded or not ?

Comment: You can try get the" ContentType" parameter, It represents the type of document.